# How to move provisioning profile to a new dev box

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've installed xcode 5.1 on a new development machine - how can I install my old provisioning profile?

Right now my provisioning profile works fine on my old Mac - do I need to disable it on old mac to be able to use it on the new one?

I've tried running a project on a device and I get the following:

> Your account already has a valid certificate If you have your signing
>   identity on another Mac, you can import a developer profile. You can
>   also revoke the current certificate and request one again.

I clicked on: Revoke and Request, but I get the message: **No code signing identity found**.

Comment: for profile u can use on different system same profile and create .p12   file for certificate export to other machine. OR you can download these from your developer account.

Comment: double click on the provision file ans .p12 key file

Comment: I have updated question. Where can I find file to get .p12?

Comment: Ok it works. As this p12 thing fix it please provide answer so I can accept it. Thanks. So basically I can install my prov. profile on any number of development machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html

You are able to export the profile and import it to a new machine.

Alternatively if you've gotten into a "bad" state you can (i believe) generate a new profile and import it to both machines.  I've successfully managed to export and import a profile once, but the last time I tried it i ended up doing something wrong and just regenerated new profiles

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your Apple Developper account in xCode and synchronize your provisionning profiles.